# Deterministic random algorythm for fetch variable array random index

Tags: algorithm, random, plsql

We need to implement lottery on PL/SQL.
Every time we have variable array with numbers and we need randomly, BUT deterministically (no `rand()`) select item using specified algorithm.
The selection must be repeatable.
Can you suggest some short pieces of code in every language for implement it on PL/SQL?

We tried:

```
M = a+b+c+d+f; a,b,c,d,f∈0;9
```

where

- `N=10000∙a+1000∙b+100∙c+10∙d+1∙f`
- `N` is array length
- `X = M/N`

Comment: google for *random number generater algorithm*

Comment: MrSmith42, yes we search much but mostly it is complex mathematic formulas.

Comment: See body of a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to AND all elements, XOR them, and finally taking the MOD to the length of the list of the elements.
The issue is that this algorithm must be repeatable with same input values.
It can not be based on random function.

Answer (score 1):

You do realize that "random but deterministic" is a contradiction in terms, right? Do you mean "pseudo-random" - meaning, "it looks random, but it can be repeated"? Is that the only issue you have?

To get "repeatable" numbers you need to set the seed to a fixed value. Here is a short demo.

```
begin
  for i in 1 .. 5 loop
    dbms_random.seed(0);
    for j in 1 .. 3 loop
      dbms_output.put_line( to_char(j) || '  ' || to_char(dbms_random.value()));
    end loop;
    dbms_output.new_line;
  end loop;
end;
/

1  .06336524584357453639006685484602123728
2  .82845982815535271890692108504429161911
3  .2318203117180902342077609254034613121

1  .06336524584357453639006685484602123728
2  .82845982815535271890692108504429161911
3  .2318203117180902342077609254034613121

1  .06336524584357453639006685484602123728
2  .82845982815535271890692108504429161911
3  .2318203117180902342077609254034613121

1  .06336524584357453639006685484602123728
2  .82845982815535271890692108504429161911
3  .2318203117180902342077609254034613121

1  .06336524584357453639006685484602123728
2  .82845982815535271890692108504429161911
3  .2318203117180902342077609254034613121
```

Then, of course, if you need to choose a "random" (pseudo-random) index of an array, say between 0 and 23 (adjust this if your indexes are from 1 and not from 0):

```
... trunc(dbms_random.value(0, 24))
```

(Note that `dbms_random.value(0, 24)` will return a value that is >= 0 and < 24).